# WSDL first WCF server where client does not send SOAPAction

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl

I am implementing a WCF web service which interacts with a client whose code I do not control. The WSDL was supplied by the client.

I generated C# files from the WSDL using SvcUtil, and besides the errors discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/626bde79-45c4-4ae2-ba7d-dd7834bacd60) I had no issues.

After hosting the service in IIS 7.0 with SSL enabled (required by the client) I attempted to get the client to make a request to the service.

At this point I got the following error:

```
The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
```

I verified that I could use the metadata published by the service along with SOAPUI to make the same request. This worked fine.

I then attempted to use SOAPUI using the WSDL supplied with the client. This failed with the same empty action error above.

I then hooked up Wireshark (enabling SSL decryption) and verified that the message sent from the client indeed lacks a SOAPAction, so it appears that this is definitely the issue.

As I cannot change the client is there a way to get a WCF web service to interact with such a client? I'm guessing it would need to accept requests with no SOAPAction and instead derive the desired request from type of the request object in the SOAP envelope?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following worked for me (based on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/1ff173ee-c371-45b1-986b-fbb67ea94de8) thread):

1. Download the Microsoft WCF examples.
2. Add the following files to your project from WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Extensibility\Interop\RouteByBody\CS\service

   - DispatchByBodyOperationSelector.cs
   - DispatchByBodyBehaviorAttribute.cs
3. Add the following attributes to your interface (next to your `ServiceContract`)

   - `XmlSerializerFormat`
   - `DispatchByBodyBehavior`
4. Add the following to your service interface

   ```
   [OperationContract(Action = "")]
   public void DoNothing()
   {
   }
   ```
5. For my service the WrapperName and Wrappernamespace are `null` for all messages. I had to go into `DispatchByBodyBehaviorAttribute` and edit `ApplyDispatchBehavior()` to add the following lines to check for this:

   ```
    if (qname.IsEmpty) {
        qname = new XmlQualifiedName(operationDescription.Messages[0].Body.Parts[0].Name, operationDescription.Messages[0].Body.Parts[0].Namespace);
    }
   ```

Comment: SPOT ON! I've just spent a few hours looking into this issue. I was trying to make my new WCF web service look identical (from a client perspective) to an older web service and was really stuck on this. I had to specify multiple empty actions to get the wsdl to match the old version, but this broke WCF. That is, until I found your answer which worked perfectly. If I could upvote you more than once, I would!

Comment: In case anybody implements this solution, and starts getting the error "This message cannot support the operation because it has been read" when debugging, see my response here that might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11170390/1373170

Comment: works great! But now my wsdl page is broken.. someone have any idea?

Comment: Just saved my bacon! I had consumed a WSDL using SvcUtil.exe that was for a Java based web service.  It generated identical Action attributes for different method calls, which WCF does not like. This solution enabled it to work so I could Emulate the Java service! Thanks!