# correct WCF service server side stub from WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have the following WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:tns="${namespace}" xmlns:wsr="http://www.openuri.org/2002/10/soap/reliability/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap12enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:conv="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/wsdl/conversation/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="${namespace}">
 <message name="addADetails">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string0">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string1">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string2">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string3">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:int" name="intVal">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string4">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string5">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string6">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string7">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string8">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="addADetailsResponse">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="result">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="addBDetails">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string0">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string1">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string2">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string3">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string4">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string5">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="addBDetailsResponse">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="result">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="deleteCDetails">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string0">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string1">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="deleteCDetailsResponse">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="result">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="queryDDetails">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string0">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string1">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="queryDDetailsResponse">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="result">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="queryEDetails">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string0">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="queryEDetailsResponse">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="result">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="updateFDetails">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string0">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string1">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string2">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string3">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:int" name="intVal">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string4">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string5">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string6">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string7">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string8">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="updateFDetailsResponse">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="result">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="updateGDetails">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string0">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string1">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string2">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string3">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string4">
  </part>
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="string5">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message name="updateGDetailsResponse">
  <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="partns:string" name="result">
  </part>
 </message>
 <portType name="TestServicePort">
  <operation name="addADetails">
   <input message="tns:addADetails">
   </input>
   <output message="tns:addADetailsResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="addBDetails">
   <input message="tns:addBDetails">
   </input>
   <output message="tns:addBDetailsResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="deleteCDetails">
   <input message="tns:deleteCDetails">
   </input>
   <output message="tns:deleteCDetailsResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="queryDDetails">
   <input message="tns:queryDDetails">
   </input>
   <output message="tns:queryDDetailsResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="queryEDetails">
   <input message="tns:queryEDetails">
   </input>
   <output message="tns:queryEDetailsResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="updateFDetails">
   <input message="tns:updateFDetails">
   </input>
   <output message="tns:updateFDetailsResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="updateGDetails">
   <input message="tns:updateGDetails">
   </input>
   <output message="tns:updateGDetailsResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding type="tns:TestServicePort" name="TestServicePort">
   <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="addADetails">
    <soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
   <input>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="addBDetails">
    <soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
   <input>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="deleteCDetails">
    <soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
   <input>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="queryDDetails">
    <soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
   <input>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="queryEDetails">
    <soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
   <input>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="updateFDetails">
    <soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
   <input>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="updateGDetails">
    <soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
   <input>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body namespace="${namespace}" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service name="TestService">
  <port name="TestServicePort" binding="tns:TestServicePort">
    <soap:address location="http://testserver:7001/test/TestService"/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

I have an existing proxy class that calls the webservice described by the WSDL. I have to create a new WCF service that can be called with the same proxy class.
I used the WSCF.blue webservices contract first tool from ThinkTecture to generate a WCF service side stub:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="${namespace}", ConfigurationName="ITestServicePort")]
public interface ITestServicePort
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/addADetails", ReplyAction="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/addADetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    string addADetails(string @string, string string0, string string1, string string2, string string3, int intVal, string string4, string string5, string string6, string string7, string string8);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/addBDetails", ReplyAction="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/addBDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    string addBDetails(string @string, string string0, string string1, string string2, string string3, string string4, string string5);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/deleteCDetails", ReplyAction="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/deleteCDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    string deleteCDetails(string @string, string string0, string string1);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/queryDDetails", ReplyAction="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/queryDDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    string queryDDetails(string @string, string string0, string string1);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/queryEDetails", ReplyAction="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/queryEDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    string queryEDetails(string @string, string string0);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/updateFDetails", ReplyAction="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/updateFDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    string updateFDetails(string @string, string string0, string string1, string string2, string string3, int intVal, string string4, string string5, string string6, string string7, string string8);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/updateGDetails", ReplyAction="${namespace}/ITestServicePort/updateGDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    string updateGDetails(string @string, string string0, string string1, string string2, string string3, string string4, string string5);
}
```

The problem is when I use the existing proxy class to call my new service it fails with a SoapHeaderException:

> The message with Action '' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to a
>   ContractFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and
>   receiver) or a binding/security
>   mismatch between the sender and the
>   receiver.  Check that sender and
>   receiver have the same contract and
>   the same binding (including security
>   requirements, e.g. Message, Transport,
>   None).

When I change one of the Action members in the OperationContractAttribute to an empty string I can call that operation successfully. When I try and change more than one Action to empty the same call fails with the following error:

> Client found response content type of
>   '', but expected 'text/xml'. The
>   request failed with an empty response.

It seems as if you cant have more than one operation with an empty Action. Is that correct?
How would I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: After I posted I saw this in the related sidebar (promised I searched before I posted :-) will have to look into it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805845/wsdl-first-wcf-server-where-client-does-not-send-soapaction

Comment: What you posted is not a WSDL.

Comment: oops. pasted wrong code. thanks. updated it.

Comment: Does the WSDL really have `${namespace}` in it? That's not a valid namespace. What namespace is the client actually expecting? Also, try looking at the network traffic using something like Fiddler or Wireshark, and/or by turning on WCF tracing. See what's actually being sent and received.

Comment: Thanks I will investigate using fiddler and wireshark (first have to learn how to use them). You are right the namespace is incorrect. I am pointing at the service on a testing box and the service description gives that namespace. Will have to find out what is the actual namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default behavior in WCF uses SOAP Action to choose which operation has to handle incomming call. For that reason Action and ReplyAction parameters in OparationContract has to be unique for single service.

You need to route your request by "body". [WCF samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395223(v=VS.90).aspxa) contains example of routing by body element. Use the same approach but instead of routing by top level wrapping element you will have to decide which operation has be called based on parameters you receive. Service described by WSDL doesn't use wrapping element.

Comment: Thank you I will look at the WCF samples of routing by body element.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I did encounter a problem with the WCF samples. The CreateMessageCopy method supplied in the sample did not work for me. I had to use CreateBufferedCopy instead.